# How to issue mysql commands remotely using Java ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, mysql, ssh, command, processbuilder

I am writing a Java program where I am issuing remote commands with [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

So I build my string like so:

```
commands.add("/bin/sh");
commands.add("-c");
commands.add("ssh root@remoteserver.com \"pgrep -f this-app\"");
```

And I get this-app PID from remoteserver.

My question is how can I do the same to issue a mysql command with -e ( passing mysql e parameter)

Example - I have tried:

```
commands.add("/bin/sh");
commands.add("-c");
commands.add("ssh root@remoteserver.com \"mysql uroot -e \"drop database exampledb;\"\" ");
```

Desired behaviour (local) :

```
Mysql -uroot -e "drop database exampledb"
```

This will drop the database if command was issued Locally and not remotely.

Similar behaviour issued from remote system:

```
/bin/sh -c "ssh root@remotesystem.com "pgrep -f this-app""
```

The same written for process builder (Working):

```
commands.add("/bin/sh");
commands.add("-c");
commands.add("ssh root@remotesystem.com \"pgrep -f this-app\"");
```

This will return the Process ID of this-app.

Desired behaviour from remote system:

```
/bin/sh -c "ssh root@remotesystem.com "mysql -uroot -e "drop database exampledb"""
```

To drop database from ssh (remotely)

But this does not work. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Please be more specific, what does not work?

Comment: That looks very risky, security-wise.  You should probably find a framework on your server which does what you need.

Comment: Use jsch better than process

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your responses. I do not want to use third party solutions such as jsch. 
To be more specific:
What does work: 
    commands.add("ssh root@remoteserver.com \"pgrep -f this-app\"");  which becomes -- ssh root@remoteserver.com "pgrep -f this-app"      .. and successfully returns app PID.
What does not work:
    commands.add("ssh root@remoteserver.com \"mysql uroot -e \"use exampledb; drop database exampledb;\"\" ");      which becomes ssh root@remoteserver.com "mysql uroot -e "use exampledb; drop database exampledb;" "

Comment: Hi all... I got it to work. Looks like it needed /bin/sh, -c, ssh root@remotesystem.com "mysql -uroot -e 'drop database exampledb'"   (REQUIRED the -uroot instead of uroot)